# how to use java.net.URLConnection to obtain a captcha image in a php web form

Tags: java, google-app-engine, httpurlconnection

I am trying to automate submission of same/similar data to web forms. AS part of this process, I want to submit data to a PHP web form that has a captcha... The captcha is defined as Img src="http://domain.com/captcha.php".... it is linked to a text field on the page named "CAPTCHA"

The page to which I want to submit data is at http://domain.com/submit.php.. I am trying to use java.net.URLConnection to open a connection to this page.

What I want to know is, how do I obtain the value of this captcha image on screen? I want the end user to fill in this captcha, and then I will submit the form to its action, along with the captcha (I already have values for all other fields).

In the Sun Documentation on Java.net.urlconnection I found the following relevant section-

"The following methods are used to access the header fields and the contents after the connection is made to the remote object:

- getContent
- getHeaderField
- getInputStream
- getOutputStream"

I cant find a good example for "getContent" which I feel should be the function to retrieve data from the web page. I plan to use URLConnection on Google App Engine for Java.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to parse the HTML page that the server returned, then you will need to find the URL of the image in that page, download the image (giving extra care to handle cookies properly), then show that to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is as you describe, the server is presumably using cookies or other session identifiers to determine which captcha was served to the user - so fetching it yourself will result in a different captcha to the one the user has to enter.

These mechanisms are designed specifically to prevent people from doing the sort of thing you seem to be trying to do, though, so I think it would be unethical to help you do this.

Comment: Nick, I have seen 2 other programs (one written in Delphi, the other in Java) that show only the captcha on screen, and when the user has filled in the captcha, then that form is submitted to its action. So it can be done, only I dont know how...

Comment: @user893664 I'm not saying it can't be done - I'm saying that the captcha is specifically designed to prevent this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, but in some scenarios, eg I am developing a keyword research software for SEO, there I would like to have some values extracted from Google Adwords Keywords Tool- so that I can then show these values along with respective keywords- I have seen many keyword research tools and some  of them show only the captcha of Google Adwords on screen- and then the form is submitted to Google, and the values extracted from the results- so in some scenarios this is a necessity...